# Changing Windows remote System Password from Linux

Tags: linux, windows, password

I'm looking for a way to change the password for some user of a Windows box remotely from a Linux Box. Really I have to do it by running some program/system script on the Linux Box but without running anything more than standard services on the windows system.

Comment: Really it is a programming question, but SO people closed it as not "programming related" so I guess it belongs to ServerFault. I write that to avoid being sent back to SO.

Comment: So is a windows box or linux box? Your title and body say two different things.

Comment: The Question on SO has been edited to be more programming related, but I'm still interrested by means to do that using shell tools on Linux.

Comment: @Erika: I'm running my script on Linux and the password of a remote Windows box should be changed.

Answer (score 3):

You can [update the "unicodePwd" attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223248(v=prot.10).aspx) of the user object using LDAP over SSL to reset a user's password. This is probably the most straightforward "cross-platform friendly" way to make such a change because, on the Linux site, you won't need any MSRPC infrastructure.

Comment: Interesting, but the asker doesn't say whether this machine is joined to a domain or not.

Comment: @gravyface: Good point. I'm so used to living in Active Directory environments that I can't imagine not having one. Definitely a good point.

Comment: Andersan: I should have said I already did that for machines that are in a domain, I'm looking for another solution for stand alone machines that are not inside a domain. But +1 anyway as I totally agree it's the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

I am somewhat in doubt about what you are going to accomplish - changing a Windows user's password? By script?

If so, take a look into [winexe](http://openports.se/net/winexe) - it uses RPC calls and allows you to run commands on the Windows machine without prior software installation (the Windows firewall must be configured for letting RPC through, tough). Running a `net user <username> <password>` on the Windows machine would do.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was looking for something using the SMB API, but winexe could indeed another way to do it.

Comment: That would be really a SO question. But you always can take winexe's source code and incorporate it into your project to run a command. In theory, you should be able to use RPC for changing the SAM account information directly - I do not know if Samba's rpcclient would support that.